# txt file modification in python

Tags: python

My file .txt format is as follow:

```
            Address        Name
            0x0802da50     xxx
            0x0802da50     xxx
```

I want to list just the Address column and write it to another txt file (the spaces before are also unnecessary). Here is what I wrote:

```
def print_address():

    input_file = 'Address&Name.txt'
    destination_file = 'Address.txt'
    
         with open(destination_file, 'a') as f1:
                with open(input_file, 'r') as f2:
                    for num, line in enumerate(f2.readlines(), 1): 
                        for word in input_file:
                            if word.startswith("0x"):
                                f1.write(f'{word}')
        print_address()
```

I get empty file, though, instead of:

```
Address
0x0..
0x0..
```

Comment: On this line `for word in input_file:` = you iterate over string `'Address&Name.txt'`, char by char.

Comment: Note that when you fix this error, and iterate over lines of file, you need to split line at space/tab in order to iterate over line word by word - `for word in line.strip().split():`

Comment: finally, you want to add new-line char at the end when you write `word` to file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to achieve tis, but with the structure you defined, you can do :

```py
input_file = 'a.txt'
destination_file = 'b.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r') as f2:
    with open(destination_file, 'a') as f1:
        contents=f2.readlines()
        for line in contents:
            word = line.split(" ")[0]
            if word.startswith("0x"):
                f1.write(f'{word}\n')
```

EDIT : So, as pointed by the comments, althought I wanted to keep your structure in my previous answer, this can be optimized.
Example :

```py
input_file = 'a.txt'
destination_file = 'b.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r') as f2, open(destination_file, 'a') as f1:
    for line in f2.readlines():
        f1.write(f'{line.split()[0]}\n')
```

will do the same job.